# В чем смысл данной конструкции?(int i{};)

Tags: c++

```
int i{};
```

Что делает данная конструкция? Насколько я понял, это переменная, но зачем нужны скобки?

Comment: Инициализирует `i` нулем (блин, никак не запомню, как эта инициализация правильно в стандарте называется :(...)

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/330402/

Comment: @Harry, агрегатная. Вроде :)

Comment: @MrBin: Нет, не агрегатная. Современная инициализация с `{}` - list-initialization, "списковая инициализация", "инициализация списком". Агрегатная инициализация - частный случай списковой инициализации, применимый только к агрегатам. `int` - не агрегат.

Comment: @Ant, да, хорошее уточнение.  Тоже забываю.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Данная конструкция - объявление с инициализатором.

Пустые скобки - `()` или `{}` - на месте инициализатора всегда означают инициализацию по умолчанию в С++. В данном случае, т.е. для типа `int`, это инициализация нулем. Аналогичные примеры в других контекстах

```
struct S 
{
  int a, b;
  S() : a(), b{}
    { assert(a == 0 && b == 0); }
};

int *a = new int();
int *b = new int{};
assert(*a == 0 && *b == 0);
```

Инициализатор `()` существует в C++ с "начала времен" (C++98), а инициализатор `{}` в такой роли появился в C++11. То есть во многих контекстах у вас есть выбор между `()` и `{}`. Однако в вашем конкретном контексте `()` в корне поменяет смысл декларатора, поэтому остается только вариант `{}`. (Собственно поэтому в С++11 возможности `{}`-синтаксиса инициализации и сделали универсальными и *основными*).

Разумеется, когда тип известен - `int` - вы можете пользоваться любым иным способом инициализации нулем, например, возможно более читаемым `int i = 0;` или `int i(0);`. Но в общем случае, особенно когда тип неизвестен, `{}` является наиболее универсальным вариантом для инициализации по умолчанию.